# Gibt es ein kurzes Gegenteil zu "eilt" / "eilig"?

Tags: single-word-request

Wenn man jemandem eine Mail schreibt und gleich im Betreff klar machen will, dass er/sie die Mail am besten sofort aufmacht, wenn sie ankommt, kann man "EILT" oder "EILIG" in den Betreff schreiben.

> [Eilt!] In welchem Küchenschrank steht der Pfeffer?

Wie ist es, wenn man der anderen Person signalisieren möchte, dass er/sie sich **nicht** beeilen muss?
Gibt es ein Wort, das möglichst nicht ähnlich zu "Eilt" aussieht, aber gleichzeitig kurz ist?

Comment: Eigentlich ist das Gegenteil von "eilig" *säumig*  - Nur würde das kein Mensch verstehen, weil das Wort anders (negativ) belegt ist.

Comment: Genau, ich würde es beim Überfliegen wahrscheinlich sogar eher als Vorwurf sehen, eine `[Eilt!]`-Mail nicht schnell genug beantwortet zu haben. So á la "Mahnung! Sie sind säumig!".

Answer (score 6):

Ich glaube, das perfekte Gegenteil gibt es nicht. Mir fallen als erstes  "Gegenteile" ein, die sich über [Eilt!] lustig machen:

> [Entspannt!]
> [Erfordert Sorgfalt!]

Etwas ernsthafter würde man es wohl umschreiben mit:

> [Hat Zeit!]
> [Eilt nicht!]

In der Praxis solte man sowas zumindest in meinem Umfeld wohl tatsächlich nicht schreiben, wenn die Sache eine Chance haben soll, überhaupt erledigt zu werden.

Comment: *In der Praxis solte man sowas zumindest in meinem Umfeld wohl tatsächlich nicht schreiben, wenn die Sache eine Chance haben soll, überhaupt erledigt zu werden.* <-- Sehr guter Punkt. :-)

Answer (score 4):

"bei Gelegenheit" ist die typischerweise verwendete Phrase.  Noch weniger Nachdruck hätte "irgendwann".  Das ist zwar formal keine Angabe der (Nicht-)Dringlichkeit; im Kontext einer Zeitraumangabe erfüllt es aber diese Funktion.